# MS Edge and IE 11 does not support html5 video element

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, microsoft-edge

For some reason I can't get IE 11 and MS Edge browsers to play html5 videos. When I go to youtube.com/html5 or html5test.com it shows that video element is not supported (even though those browsers should support it). I have tried everything, reset all settings, even reinstalled ms edge through powershell, installed media feature pack and still no change. I guess there is some setting that I am not aware of, but after searching internet for hours did not find anything. Any ideas why video (and audio too) element might be not supported at all for Egde and IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok it seems I had bad media feature pack which did not install anything: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-n-media-feature-pack-not-working-after/953d600b-badd-4fdb-8756-6eb3b740d02e

After installing from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229 it works. Need to be careful as I think google best result returns wrong update link.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only thing that helped is installing the correct `Media Feature Pack` from [microsoft downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack).

In order to find out which one is compatible with your OS, go to `Settings -> About your PC`, check the section `Windows Specifications`, `Version`. In my case I had version `1803` so I installed `Media Feature Pack - Version 1803 (April)`.

The latest media pack (at the time of this post) `1809` of October 2018 wasn't compatible with my OS and couldn't be installed but after installing the correct media pack videos started working in `Edge` and `IE`.